# I need to select a data that doesn't exist on a table as zero using the COUNT() function, how do I do so using Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

For instance:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(num) AS number, Status
FROM base
WHERE Status in ('P', 'J', 'K') 
GROUP BY Status;
```

Note: J and K doesn't exist in the Status column but I need to display the number as zero

The result should be like:

```
number | Status
---------------
1500   | P
0      | J
0      | K
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use derived table and `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT count(base.num) AS number, s.Status 
FROM (SELECT 'P' AS Status UNION ALL SELECT 'J' UNION ALL SELECT 'K') s
LEFT JOIN base ON s.status = base.Status
group by s.Status;
```

Comment: You should use `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Most likely Gordon is making this suggestion because `UNION ALL`, which is not concerned with removing duplicates, would outperform `UNION`, which would have to do extra work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh, excuse me, I misread as `UNION ALL` **or** `UNION`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind having the results as *columns*, rather than rows, then we can try using conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'P' THEN 1 END) AS p_cnt,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'J' THEN 1 END) AS j_cnt,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'K' THEN 1 END) AS k_cnt
FROM base;
```

The derived table idea suggested by @Lukasz is a good one, and you should probably have a separate table for the stati in any case.

Comment: But this gives pivoted results, while the OP wants to have unpivoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily `UNPIVOT` your data by using `UNION ALL` as

```
SELECT COUNT(num) AS number, coalesce(Status,'P') AS Status FROM base WHERE Status = 'P' 
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(num)          , coalesce(Status,'J')           FROM base WHERE Status = 'J' 
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(num)          , coalesce(Status,'K')           FROM base WHERE Status = 'K';
```

If some rows are inserted with Status `'J'` or `'K'` and `num > 0` in the future, you'll be able to get count values more than zero for those rows also.

Answer (score 0):

What you should probably do is fix your data model so you have a `statuses` reference table:

```
create tables statuses (
    status char(1) primary key,
    description varchar(255),
    createdAt datetime default curent_datetime
);
```

You might have other information to store as well.

Populate this table:

```
insert into statuses (status, description)
    values ('P', 'P status'),
           ('J', 'J status'),
           ('K', 'K status');
```

You might find better descriptions.

Declare a proper foreign key relationship:

```
alter table base add constraint fk_base_status foreign key (status) references statuses(status);
```

Then use a `left join`:

```
select s.status, count(b.status)
from statuses s left join
     base b
     on s.status = b.status
group by s.status;
```